# Manually trigger `autocompleteselect` in jQueryUI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've got a custom rendering solution set up using jQuery Autocomplete.

```
// save a reference to the widget itself to override methods
var widget = $('#ui-search').on('autocompleteselect', function(e) {
    console.log('I am tracking the events from OUTSIDE');
}).autocomplete({
    /***** REMOVE THIS and 'autocompleteselect' does nothing *****/
    select: function(ui, item) {
        console.warn('I am tracking this from INSIDE');  
    },
    /***** *****/
    source: projects

}).data('ui-autocomplete');

// bind clicks on the autocomplete list to trigger the 'select' event
$('.ui-autocomplete').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var item = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete-item');
    // use the widget's internal trigger method for generating the right kinds of events
    widget._trigger('select', $.Event('autocompleteselect'), item);
})

// this is the custom rendering method and is only relevant in that it does not include an anchor tag
widget._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" ).data('ui-autocomplete-item', item).html(item.label + "<br>" + item.desc).appendTo( ul );
};
```

[Live demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGu2h/8/)

The end result I'm trying to achieve is that a click on the list item will select that option, while a click on a button *inside* the element will show an info panel on for that selection. (That part is done and not relevant.)

**The autocomplete widget does not respond to an `autocompleteselect` event unless I have defined a custom `select` handler.** If I remove the custom `select` method, the widget does nothing. I can define a custom handler to set the value of the input and close the suggest list, but I can't figure out why the default handler doesn't fire.

Has anyone had success triggering `autocomplete` events and having the default handlers respond? Does anyone know why this doesn't (or possibly *shouldn't*) work the way I'm expecting?

---

The fiddle is using jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.9.2; locally I am using jQuery 1.9.1 and UI 1.10.3. There is no difference in behavior between environments.

Comment: What version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: @haim770 $1.9.1, UI1.9.2; added to the post.

Comment: Downvote without comment? What am I missing?

Comment: I just +1 because i agree this is more than a legitimate question.